# personal program through a vpn like hamachi or open vpn?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, vpn

I'm making a simple game than uses udp or tcp sockets to connect in c.
I've gotten vpn set up before and used the default vpn chats.
I'm just wondering how do I make my program work?
What port do I use? How do I make connect through the vpn?
I know just typing in the vpn address doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all of this should depend on how you have things set up. The VPN software will connect to each other using the ports and hostnames or IPs you have designated.

The game you say you are designing: is this supposed to be a two person thing, so they will have to talk? In that case, you specific whatever port you desire in the code when you are making it.

Hope this is what you are looking for :-)